# Bad Alignment when Hiding and Unhiding Divs on Hover

Tags: html, css, alignment

Right now I have a button that has a dropdown to reveal two buttons below it. My problem is it messes with the other buttons' alignment when the dropdown happens.

One thing to consider is they need to "make space" for the drop downs when the screen goes to mobile (because the buttons stack on top of each other).

So right now, it works how I like in mobile and I'm looking for a solution for desktop, or possibly a new solution that makes both work.

My one wishlist item would be to have a transition for the dropdown, but my current solution uses display:none for two reasons: because the buttons are transparent so I can't hide something behind them, and in mobile, I can't preserve space below it because they are stacked on each other.

[zackpyle.com/photography](http://zackpyle.com/photography/)

```
<style>
.wrapcenter{
  text-align:center;
}
.homebox{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  margin:25px; 
  border:1px; 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:white;
  width:250px; 
  height:140px;
  color:white;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
h4.homeboxtext{
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.homebox:hover {
 background:rgba(255,255,255,.4)
    }

h4{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "Abel";
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
h5{
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-family: "Abel";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  transform: translate(0%, -70%);
}
.submenu {
  display: none;
  margin:25px; 
  border:1px; 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:white;
  width:250px; 
  height:50px;
  color:white;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}
.div_one:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}
.homeboxphotography_wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>


    <div class="container wrapcenter">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/professional-gallery">
              <h5>Professional</h5>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/fun-gallery">
              <h5>For Fun</h5>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="menu1">
                <h5>Travel</h5>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/europe-gallery">Mainland Europe</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/iceland-gallery">Iceland</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Zack

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from inline-block to float.

```
.homeboxphotography_wrapper {
float: left;
}
```

Will be best to add media queries to stack those elements for tablet devices.

Another method would be to use position absolute on the child elements, make sure they are within a container.

Comment: Thank you. I had that at one point, but the float:left un-centers the buttons. Thoughts to counteract that but still get the alignment good?

Comment: Will be easier for me to give you another solutions that doesn't push down the content if you create a fiddle / codepen.

Ideally, you will want to wrap the hidden button elements in a container and set the visibility to hidden and position to absolute. From there, you can make it so when you hover over the main parent element, you can show the buttons below it without effecting the height of anything. On tablet / mobile devices, this will cause unwanted effect, so you'll want to create media query that simply does what you have it doing now.

Comment: FYI for anyone, I just created media queries to handle the alignment for different screen sizes. Thanks for the help!